# SQL Puzzle with Dynamic LAG and/or resetting a cumulative SUM

Tags: sql, lag, netezza

Here's a puzzle for you... I have been banging my head against the wall with this for 2 days. :-) Help!!

**Background**: My dataset has Customers with 1 row per event with Start and End dates.

**Goal**: I need to add a MAIN_EVENT flag to certain events as illustrated here.  (*The "Set" column would be nice but is not explicitly necessary; explained below.*)

**The rules**:  A "Main Event" is any event that STARTS >30 days after the PREVIOUS "Main Event" ENDS.

**Simple example**: As shown below, "Smith 1" ends on 01/09; since "Smith 2 and 3" START within 30 days after that, they are *not* "Main Events". "Smith 4" however does start >30 days after "Smith 1" ends and thus needs to be flagged as a new "Main Event". I can already solve this part (i.e. finding the SECOND "Main Event") using a running SUM(), but that's where the problems begin.

**The Real Problem**:  Now that the 4th "Smith" event has been flagged as a "Main Event", I now need to compare future events against the END_DATE for "Smith 4" and not "Smith 1". (e.g. "Smith 5" is not a "Main Event" because it starts within 30 days of "Smith 4" end.

Regarding the "Set" Column: I added the "Set" column here just to illustrate the related rows, i.e. where a "Main Event" has been flagged and the remaining events starting in that 30-day window that are not "Main Events". I don't explicitly need this, but it might be nice to have.

If my explanation is not too confusing, I hope this will be an easy (and fun?) puzzle for someone with better SQL expertise than mine! :-)  p.s. I'm running this on a NETEZZA database.

**Thank you!!**

| CUST | SEQ | START_DATE | END_DATE | MAIN_EVENT | Set | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SMITH | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-09 | 1 | 1 | MAIN EVENT because it's first for this customer. |
| SMITH | 2 | 2020-01-16 | 2020-01-18 | 0 | 1 | Starts within 30 days of the last Main Event's End, i.e. BEFORE 2020-02-08 |
| SMITH | 3 | 2020-01-28 | 2020-02-02 | 0 | 1 | Starts within 30 days of the last Main Event's End, i.e. BEFORE 2020-02-08 |
| SMITH | 4 | 2020-02-23 | 2020-02-28 | 1 | 2 | MAIN EVENT. Starts >30 days AFTER the last Main Event's End, i.e. AFTER 2020-02-08 |
| SMITH | 5 | 2020-03-09 | 2020-03-11 | 0 | 2 | Starts within 30 days of the last Main Event's End, i.e. BEFORE 2020-03-29 |
| SMITH | 6 | 2020-05-10 | 2020-05-15 | 1 | 3 | MAIN EVENT. Starts >30 days AFTER the last Main Event's End, i.e. AFTER 2020-03-29 |
| SMITH | 7 | 2020-08-13 | 2020-08-21 | 1 | 4 | MAIN EVENT. Starts >30 days AFTER the last Main Event's End, i.e. AFTER 2020-06-14 |
| SMITH | 8 | 2020-08-26 | 2020-09-05 | 0 | 4 | Starts within 30 days of the last Main Event's End, i.e. BEFORE 2020-09-20 |
| SMITH | 9 | 2020-09-12 | 2020-10-02 | 0 | 4 | Starts within 30 days of the last Main Event's End, i.e. BEFORE 2020-09-20 |
| JONES | 1 | 2020-01-15 | 2020-01-25 | 1 | 1 | MAIN EVENT because it's first for this customer. |
| JONES | 2 | 2020-05-01 | 2020-05-06 | 1 | 2 | MAIN EVENT. Starts >30 days AFTER the last Main Event's End, i.e. AFTER 2020-02-24 |

Comment: This logic requires a recursive CTE or hierarchical query and I don't think that Netezza has that functionality.  You will need to do a loop outside the database.

Comment: Gordon, I suspect you're exactly right. Thank you for reviewing this puzzle. I appreciate your expertise!